# Calculate $\iint_{R}\frac{y}{x}\,dx\,dy$ if $R$ is the region limited by $\frac{y^{2}}{x}=1$, $\frac{y^{2}}{x}=5$, $xy=1$, and $xy=6$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Calculate
>   $$\iint_{R}\frac{y}{x}\,dx\,dy$$
>   if $R$ is the region limited by 
>   \begin{align}
> \frac{y^{2}}{x}&=1 \\
> \frac{y^{2}}{x}&=5 \\
> xy&=1 \\
> xy&=6 \\
> \end{align}

I made the obvious substitutions $u=\frac{y^{2}}{x}$ and $v=xy$, but then I couldn't get the function $f(x,y)=\frac{y}{x}$ written in terms of $u$ and $v$. Do I need a better substitution to work this out?

The area of integration is supposed to be the black part in this diagram.

[image]

Comment: The region, as is, is empty. Could you fix that?

Comment: I added in a picture

Comment: If $u = y^2/x$ and $v=xy$, then $y/x = (u^2/v)^{1/3}$. I don't know if that helps.

Comment: Notice $uv=y^3$. So you can get $y$, and then get $x$, from $u,v$. Don't forget the Jacobian determinant $${\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y=\det\begin{bmatrix} \displaystyle \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \displaystyle \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\ \displaystyle \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \displaystyle \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \end{bmatrix}\,{\rm d}u\,{\rm d}v. $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Note that:

$$v^2=x^2y^2 \implies \frac{v^2}{x^3}=\frac{y^2}{x}=u \implies x=(v^2/u)^{1/3}$$

Hence $$y=\frac{v}{x}=(uv)^{1/3}$$

Comment: I couldn't figura that out haha. If I make a substitution like the one I made, am I always guaranteed to be able to write the function $f(x,y)$ in terms of $u,v$?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Well, in general I'm not sure, one would need to define rigorously what we mean by "a substitution", it probably depends on whether the functions involved are injective and surjective. However, in practice I would say that you should be able to do it, since the functions involved should be reasonably "nice".

Answer (score 0):

We introduce new variables $u$ and $v$ by means of
$$u=xy,\quad v={y^2\over x}\ .\tag{1}$$
Solving these equations for $x$ and $y$ gives
$$x=u^{2/3}\>v^{-1/3},\quad y=u^{1/3}\>v^{1/3}\ .\tag{2}$$ Since we could uniquely invert $(1)$ in the form of $(2)$ it follows that
$$f:\quad[1,6]\times[1,5]\to R,\qquad (u,v)\to (x,y)$$
defined by $(2)$ is a bijective parametrization of $R$. One easily computes
$$J_f(u,v)=\det\left[\matrix{x_u&x_v\cr y_u&y_v\cr}\right]={1\over3}v^{-1}\ .$$
We therefore have
$$\eqalign{\int_R{y\over x}\>{\rm d}(x,y)&=\int_{[1,6]\times[1,5]} u^{-1/3}\>v^{2/3}\>J_f(u,v)\>{\rm d}(u,v)\cr &=\int_1^6\int_1^5 u^{-1/3}\>v^{2/3}\>{1\over3}v^{-1}\>dv\>du\cr &={3\over4}(6^{2/3}-1)(5^{2/3}-1)\ .\cr}$$

Comment: Why does that already shows that the map is bijective?